# Python : How to insert a dictionary to a sqlite database?

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary

I have a sqlite database with a table with following columns :

```
id(int) , name(text) , dob(text)
```

I want to insert following dictionary to it :

```
{"id":"100","name":"xyz","dob":"12/12/12"}
```

Dictionary keys are the column names. How can i achieve it ?

Comment: What have you tried? How are you connecting to the database? Are you using any kind of ORM?

Comment: Can you please provide some code you have Tried ??

Comment: you cannot insert a dictionary easily, but you can insert a list. Have a look [at the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany)

Comment: A possible solution would be to modify the Class IterChars() in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library[/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) . I was not able to adapt it though. A look at [sqlalchemy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SQLAlchemy/1.0.0b4) might help as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert Values from dictionary into sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049332/insert-values-from-dictionary-into-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 18):

To use dictionaries directly you can do:

```
user1 = {"id":100, "name": "Rumpelstiltskin", "dob": "12/12/12"}
c.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (:id, :name, :dob)", user1)
```

Using along with instances/models:

```
class User:                                                                      

    def __init__(self, name, dob):                                            
        self.name = name                                                             
        self.dob = dao  

u1 = User("Rumpelstiltskin", "12/12/12")
c.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (:name, :dob)", u1.__dict__)
```

id is a keyword in Python, so if you want to use it as an identifier of an instance variable I would recommend using _id (and the same as your table's primary key name).

Answer (score 16):

Looking at the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) you can add a single row:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?)", [dict["id"], dict["name"], dict["dob"]])
```

Or you can use a list and add multiple rows in one go:

```
# Larger example that inserts many records at a time
purchases = [('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
             ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
             ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
            ]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', purchases)
```

Comment: Maybe update this to show how a list of the asker's dictionaries can be inserted? With that I think your answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a way which preserves parameter safety. (Might need polishing in the tablename department)

```
def post_row(conn, tablename, rec):
    keys = ','.join(rec.keys())
    question_marks = ','.join(list('?'*len(rec)))
    values = tuple(rec.values())
    conn.execute('INSERT INTO '+tablename+' ('+keys+') VALUES ('+question_marks+')', values)

row = {"id":"100","name":"xyz","dob":"12/12/12"}
post_row(my_db, 'my_table', row)
```

Answer (score 7):

If, for example, `c = conn.cursor()`, and your dictionary is named `dict` and your table `tablename`, then you can write

```
c.execute('insert into tablename values (?,?,?)', [dict['id'], dict['name'], dict['dob']])
```

Which will insert the elements of the dictionary into the table as you require.

Answer (score 2):

As per Gareth‘s response, if you're using `MySQLdb` you can use `executemany` and pass a list of values which you can get directly from your `dict` using `dict.values()`

Comment: Be careful to sort when using this method as the cursor will INSERT based on order and dictionaries do not maintain order.

Comment: small update: Dictionaries now maintain order as of 3.6, and this behavior will be in language specification as of 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function which uses the dictionary keys as table columns, the order is also not important with this approach, just that the table uses auto incremental `id` column:

```py
def insert_into(table, dictionary):
    dictionary["id"] = None
    insert_query = f"INSERT INTO {table} "
    dictionary_keys = dictionary.keys()
    columns = ""
    values_placeholders = " VALUES "
    for index, column in enumerate(dictionary_keys):
        if index == 0:
            columns += "("
            values_placeholders += "("
        columns += f"{column}"
        values_placeholders += f":{column}"
        if index + 1 != len(dictionary_keys):
            columns += ", "
            values_placeholders += ", "
        else:
            columns += ")"
            values_placeholders += ")"

    insert_query += columns + values_placeholders

    cursor.execute(insert_query, dictionary)

insert_into('your_table', {"name":"xyz","dob":"12/12/12"})
```