# How to insert multiple rows from a python nested dictionary to a sqlite db

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, sqlite

I read a yaml file and extract values into a python list. I want to dump the values into a sqlite db and the structure of the list is nested. I have attempted various methods of storing the data in my db, as seen below but they don't solve the problem.

When the lists of the format ('a','b','c') I am able to insert into the table without issues. But when I have a key-value pair, I run into issues.

```
Data structure: 
 [   {   'CPU': 2,
    'jobname': 'Job1',
    'memory': '4 GB',
    'problem': 'Prob1',
    'team': '1'},
{   'CPU': 4,
    'jobname': 'Job2',
    'memory': '256 GB',
    'problem': 'Prob3',
    'team': '3'},
{   'CPU': 5,
    'jobname': 'Job3',
    'memory': '8 GB',
    'problem': 'Prob5',
    'team': '1'}]
```

This is what I tried but it looks their data structure is slightly different: [Python : How to insert a dictionary to a sqlite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913080/python-how-to-insert-a-dictionary-to-a-sqlite-database)

```
# read data from the config file
def read_yaml(file):
    with open(file, "r") as stream:
        try:
            config = yaml.safe_load(stream)
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            print(exc)
            print("\n")
    return config

    q = read_yaml("queue.yaml")

  # establish connection to sqlite database and save into db
 conn = sqlite3.connect('queues.db')
 c = conn.cursor()

 # create a sqlite3 database to store the dictionary values
 def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS queues(job TEXT, team 
       TEXT, problem TEXT, CPU INT, memory TEXT)")

 create_table()

 # insert data into the table
def dynamic_data_entry():
    for item in q:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO queues VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", item)
    conn.commit()

dynamic_data_entry()
```

This is the output error : Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "queue_info.py", line 50, in <module>
dynamic_data_entry()
File "queue_info.py", line 47, in dynamic_data_entry
c.execute("INSERT INTO queues VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", item)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Binding 1 has no name, but you supplied a 
 dictionary (which has only names).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqlite3` supports [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) using the placeholder syntax `:[key]` in place of `?`.
You can also use [executemany](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) instead of `for item in q:`

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO queues (job, team, problem, CPU, memory) VALUES
    (:jobname, :team, :problem, :CPU, :memory);", data)
```

Comment: thank you! I may have a follow-up question about deeply nested dictionaries like Data structure: 
 Data = [   {   'CPU': 2,
    'jobname': '[Queue': Job1', 'Queue2': 'Job3'],
    'memory': '4 GB',
    'problem': 'Prob1',
    'team': '1'}, How can I handle such a case within my sqlite insertion?

Comment: afaik you'll need to preprocess the dicts to normalize them into a flat list before inserting.